# Where do neutral monist believes that the innate nature of things lie?

Tags: metaphysics

Where do neutral monist believes that the innate nature of things lie? Neutral monists believes that things are expressed physically and inside of our consciousness, but the innate nature of things are never fully expressed to us. Given this, where do neutral monists believe that the innate nature of things lie, in what realm can we observe the innate nature of things or do the innate nature of things exist?

Comment: Doesnt the fact that we eat stuff around us imply that we can know interval (innate) aspects of Nature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ii think that with the innate Nature of things they litterally mean what is inside it. So, what is inside an elementary particle. This can't be other material particles bu instead this is a kind of charge. People themselves are made of elementary particles but they don't consider this charge. Only the physical aspects are considered when looking at conscienceness. They are agnostic (neutral) when the Nature of the innate (charge) is considered.